# How can we update displayed text in cml:text or cml:textarea using javascript on crowdflower platform?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, crowdflower

I am designing crowdsourcing interface on crowdflower platform, during design, I need `cml:text` or `cml:textarea` to accept workers's text input. Here is an example:

```
<cml:textarea label="my_name" id="my_id" validates="required" default="123456"/>
```

The default value shown in this text box is "123456", however, it will disappear after user clicking. What if I want to preload some content which can be reused (**doesn't disappear**) by the workers? I tried the following methods:

```
document.getElementById('my_id').html() = "678910";
document.getElementById('my_id').innerHTML ="678910";
document.getElementById('my_id').value = "678910";
document.getElementById('my_id').default = "678910";
document.getElementById('my_id').placeholder = "678910";
document.getElementByName('my_name').html() = "678910";
...
```

None of them works. Is it doable to update text in `cml:text` or `cml:textarea` on crowdflower platform?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today! It seems that `document.getElementById` or its alternatives do not work for cml input tags. Here is a workaround using jQuery that worked for me. Put your `cml:textarea` in a `div`, then use `find` to get the inputs inside the parent `div`.

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
  var my_element = $("#parent_element_id").find("input")[0]; // first input element in the list
  my_element.value = "678910";
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your method by putting two `cml:textarea` in `div` and adding `<script type="text/Javascript">` with your jQuery code, but it didn't update the content. Even if I separate CML and jQuery in two boxes, it still doesn't work. Any problems for my try?